# Need assistance optimizing `each` iteration

Tags: ruby, iteration

I have `@acct_list`:

```
{"account_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>0.0, 0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>0.0}
{"account_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>1000.0, 0=>2, 1=>nil, 2=>1000.0}
{"account_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>9.0, 0=>3, 1=>2, 2=>9.0}
{"account_id"=>4, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>0.0, 0=>4, 1=>2, 2=>0.0}
```

I am attempting to display customer #'s and account #'s for a bank program. I would like my display to read something like this:

```
Customer #1 Account #1  -----  Balance: $0.0

            Account #2  -----  Balance: $1000.0

Customer #2 Account #3  -----  Balance: $9.0

            Account #4  -----  Balance: $0.0
```

Each customer should be displayed only once with the total amount of accounts that the customer has.

This is what my code looks like:

```
def self.account_info2(acct_list)
  account_id_array = []
  acct_list.each do |a|
    print "\n"
    print 'Customer #' + a["customer_id"].to_s + ' Account #' + a["account_id"].to_s + "  -----  " + "Balance: $" +
    a["balance"].to_s
    print "\n"
    account_id_array.push(a["account_id"])
  end
  account_id_array
end
@acct_list = bank.account_list(@man_name, @man_pin)
return account_info2(@acct_list)
```

It displays unnecessary duplicates of the `Customer #`:

```
Customer #1 Account #1  -----  Balance: $0.0

Customer #1 Account #2  -----  Balance: $1000.0

Customer #2 Account #3  -----  Balance: $9.0

Customer #2 Account #4  -----  Balance: $0.0
```

Comment: Your desired output is misleading! It shows account 2 as belonging to customer 1 when, in fact, it does not belong to him.

Comment: Something's wrong. Either your output, or your sample data.

Comment: Sorry. Was a typo. It does in fact belong. Simple mistake. Fixed error.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make a few changes. 1. Represent the last four lines as a (named) array, such as `arr = [{"account_id"=>1,...,2=>0.0},...'`. 2. Move `arr` to the beginning and say you are given this array. 3. State that the elements of the array are grouped by customer, and that if the value of `"customer_id"` is `nil` it is in the same customer group as the previous element. 4. State your question: how do you print the elements of `arr` so that it look like this:.

Comment: I suggested #1 above because the last four lines do not together constitute a valid Ruby object. That's almost guaranteed to attract downvotes.

Comment: You edited the question to completely change the meaning. Worse, you did so without telling readers that you had. Such changes can render answers and comments meaningless. My answer is evidence of that. The most significant aspect of your initial questions is that values of `"customer_id" could be `nil`. You changed that in complete silence. I rarely downvote questions but here I've made an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@acct_list = [
  {"account_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>0.0, 0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>0.0},
  {"account_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>1000.0, 0=>2, 1=>nil, 2=>1000.0},
  {"account_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>9.0, 0=>3, 1=>2, 2=>9.0},
  {"account_id"=>4, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>0.0, 0=>4, 1=>2, 2=>0.0}
]

@acct_list.chunk{|h| h["customer_id"]}
.each do |customer, a| a
  .each.with_index do |h, i|
    puts \
      (("Customer ##{customer}" if i.zero?)).to_s.ljust(11) +
      "Account ##{h["account_id"]}  -----  Balance: $#{h["balance"]}",
      nil
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Customer #1 Account #1  -----  Balance: $0.0

            Account #2  -----  Balance: $1000.0

Customer #2 Account #3  -----  Balance: $9.0

            Account #4  -----  Balance: $0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** My solution answers the original question. If you are interested in knowing what that was, look at the question's revision history.

Your (modified) array of hashes is:

```
arr = [{ "account_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>1,   "balance"=>0.0 },
       { "account_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>nil, "balance"=>1000.0 },
       { "account_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>1,   "balance"=>500.0 },
       { "account_id"=>4, "customer_id"=>2,   "balance"=>9.0 },
       { "account_id"=>5, "customer_id"=>2,   "balance"=>0.0 }]
```

This is one simple way to print the contents of `arr` in the desired format:

```
CUST_ID_SIZE = 1
CUST_ID_FILLER = ' '*("Customer # ".size + CUST_ID_SIZE)
  #=> "            "

last_id = nil
arr.each do |h|
  if h["customer_id"] && h["customer_id"] != last_id
    last_id = h["customer_id"]
    print "Customer # #{ h["customer_id"] }"
  else
    print CUST_ID_FILLER
  end
    puts " Account # #{ h["account_id"] } -----  Balance: $ #{ h["balance"] }\n\n"
end
Customer # 1 Account # 1 -----  Balance: $ 0.0

             Account # 2 -----  Balance: $ 1000.0

             Account # 3 -----  Balance: $ 500.0

Customer # 2 Account # 4 -----  Balance: $ 9.0

             Account # 5 -----  Balance: $ 0.0
```

Comment: yeah, this can probably be simplified a bit :)

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. I decided to use a machete.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `group_by` would help you out here. You have a bunch of account data that you need grouped by `customer_id` and then processed for output.

`group_by` returns a hash where the keys are the grouping items (`customer_id`'s) and the values are an array of the inputs. You don't really need the keys, so call `.values` on the result to make `customer_accounts` an array of arrays where each array element contains an array of hashes for each account associated with one customer. Like this:

`[[{"account_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>0.0}, {"account_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>1000.0}], [{"account_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>9.0}, {"account_id"=>4, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>0.0}]]`

Then iterate over `customer_accounts` to get each customer's info and iterate over each `customer` using the `with_index` option so that you can assign the `Customer #` only to the first one and the needed spacing to all others, collecting all results into the `account_output` string.

```
account_list = [{"account_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>0.0}, 
{"account_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>1, "balance"=>1000.0}, 
{"account_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>9.0}, 
{"account_id"=>4, "customer_id"=>2, "balance"=>0.0}]

def account_info(acct_list)
  account_output = ""

  customer_accounts = acct_list.group_by { |account| account['customer_id'] }.values

  customer_accounts.each do |customer|
    customer.each_with_index do |account, index|
      if index == 0
        account_output += "Customer ##{account['customer_id']} Account ##{account['account_id']} ----- Balance: $#{account['balance']}\n"
      else
        account_output += "            Account ##{account['account_id']} ----- Balance: $#{account['balance']}\n"
      end
    end
  end

  print account_output

end

account_info(account_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [
    {"account_id" => 1, "customer_id" => 1, "balance" => 0.0, 0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 0.0},
    {"account_id" => 2, "customer_id" => 1, "balance" => 1000.0, 0 => 2, 1 => nil, 2 => 1000.0},
    {"account_id" => 3, "customer_id" => 2, "balance" => 9.0, 0 => 3, 1 => 2, 2 => 9.0},
    {"account_id" => 4, "customer_id" => 2, "balance" => 0.0, 0 => 4, 1 => 2, 2 => 0.0}
]

list.chunk{|h| h["customer_id"]}.each { |customer_id, customer_data|
    msg = "Customer # #{customer_id}"
    cust_id_filter = ' ' * (msg.size)
    customer_data.each { |h|
        print (msg ? msg : cust_id_filter) + " Account # #{h["account_id"]} ---- Balance: $ #{h["balance"]}\n\n"
        msg = nil if msg
    }
}
```

you should your output:

```
Customer # 1 Account # 1 ---- Balance: $ 0.0

             Account # 2 ---- Balance: $ 1000.0

Customer # 2 Account # 3 ---- Balance: $ 9.0

             Account # 4 ---- Balance: $ 0.0
```